# How to join computer to domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I have a **DC** running **Windows Server 2012** with an internal IP of **172.31.27.158**. It is both a **DC and a DNS Server.**

Here's proof that DNS is running fine:

[image]

The machine that I would like to add to the domain has an internal IP of **172.31.18.222**

When I run **ipconfig** on the client machine I get:

[image]

However, when I try to add it to the domain, I get this:

[image]

Here's the full message:

> Note: This information is intended for a network administrator.  If
>   you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator
>   that you received this information, which has been recorded in the
>   file C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.
>
> DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource
>   record used to locate a domain controller for domain "contoso.com":
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.contoso.com
>
> The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
>   win-ld81qu9k4eu.contoso.com
>
> However no domain controllers could be contacted.
>
> Common causes of this error include:
>
> - Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect
>     addresses.
> - Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.

Here are my IPv4 settings:

[image]
[image]

Also here are the group security settings:

[image]

**How do I add a machine to the domain?**

Comment: What is the output of `nslookup contoso.com`?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/eeznvjrHnl6P

Comment: Can they ping each other? Are there any firewalls between?

Comment: @ChrisS yes indeed they can ping each other\

Comment: Can you confirm that you have promoted it to a DC and not just added the role? 2012 made it a 2 step process.

Comment: @JessePaxson can you please point out how to do that?

Comment: Start with running DCDIAG from an elevated command prompt on the DC.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/3WcJJwtsm6c

Comment: @JessePaxson everything passed: http://pastebin.com/3iDJa7bP

Comment: Have you checked the firewall on the DC?

Comment: Does your DNS forward lookup zone for the domain have an A record for `win-ld81qu9k4eu.contoso.com`? The SRV record for the DC was found, identifying `win-ld81qu9k4eu.contoso.com` as the DC to contact, but `win-ld81qu9k4eu.contoso.com` couldn't be contacted, leading me to believe that there's no A record for `win-ld81qu9k4eu.contoso.com` in the zone.

Comment: @joeqwerty yes it does: http://screencast.com/t/gSBw7WwAz

Comment: @JessePaxson looks like firewall is ok http://screencast.com/t/laV4Dc29ZkGn

Comment: No. That's not showing the A record for the DC itself. Expand and highlight the `Contoso.com` zone and post a screenshot showing the A record for the DC (or the lack thereof).

Comment: @joeqwerty sorry my sysadmin skills are almost nonexistent, were you referring to this? http://screencast.com/t/Su19slZjC4

Comment: @joeqwerty revised: http://screencast.com/t/aVcnDyysy7aY

Comment: Isnt the domain supposed to be corp.contoso.com? I though domain.tld wasn't an option in 2012 r2.

Comment: What are those security rules for? Are they for ec2 instance to ec2 instance communication (computer to computer)? If so, then that's probably the problem. You need to allow the appropriate communication between the two machines in order to join the domain. You probably need to just allow all traffic between the two to simplify this.

Comment: @joeqwerty but joe, they are able to ping each other and they are on the same VPC

Comment: yes they are 2 separate ec2 instances on the same vpc

Comment: The ICMP rule was listed at the top... But that doesn't mean that the communication you need is allowed.

Comment: ive enabled basically everything, should i enable all UDP and all TCP?

Comment: Yes, unblock (allow) all traffic. For a list of the actual ports, see here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2011/11/01/active-directory-firewall-ports-let-s-try-to-make-this-simple

Comment: jeez, @joeqwerty do you recommend i download that tool?

Comment: There is a port list about half way through the article he provided. Make sure they are all open on the firewall.

Comment: What tool? The link was meant as a reference for the ports required for AD communication through a firewall. My suggestion would be that you unblock (allow) all traffic between these two instances through the firewall. The firewall is relevant only to these instances, right? It doesn't govern external access to your instances does it?

Comment: well it looks like the firewall is completely down, yet i'm still having trouble with connecting that machine to the domain: http://screencast.com/t/4vgyA0Ep4

Comment: **This is Amazon AWS EC2, a virtual server.** You cannot connect without running a VPN connection between the two.

Comment: @cybermonkey that is incorrect

Comment: @Yuck If it's not AWS EC2, then someone has *seriously* ripped off their Security Groups page. What firewall are you using? The *only* other way to connect is 'throw open the doors' which you shouldn't even be considering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that there's a firewall between the client and server that is blocking the communication required for the client to join the domain.

My suggestion would be that if the firewall is relevant only to these two instances that you unblock (allow) all traffic through the firewall between these two instances.

Comment: two things...one is that I've posted a related question in response to your suggestion about enabling every port listed on that website: http://serverfault.com/questions/649284/windows-firewall-some-ports-not-listening  and the other question to you is how is it possible to simply allow all traffic between two nodes ?

Comment: well it looks like the firewall is completely down, yet i'm still having trouble with connecting that machine to the domain: http://screencast.com/t/4vgyA0Ep4

Comment: Wrong Firewall. I'm referring to the firewall you posted in your question, not the Windows Firewall. Also, undo any changes you made to the Windows Firewall (your port rules).

Comment: crap............

Comment: that worked!!!!! but that solution SUCKS! :) i dont want to allow ALL traffic

Comment: thank you so much for your time and efforts joe! i learned a TON

Comment: Glad to help. So my question is this: Is the firewall relevant only to these two instances or does it control external access to the instances as well?

Comment: its just going to be relevant to maybe 5 machines thats it

Comment: @joeqwerty It's Amazon AWS EC2, the firewall can control access both ways (external access and internal).

Comment: please also check out http://serverfault.com/questions/649354/how-to-enable-internet-connection-on-ec2 and let me know if you might have any suggestions? i'm running into this issue with the non-DC machines

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the DNS record for the DC could not have been found.

Have you tried adding the DC's IP to the preferred DNS servers under the computers IPv4 settings?

[image]

Comment: shalom itai. thanks for your help. i've included my settings for that in my question just now. please scroll down to the bottom of my question