# windows firewall , some ports not listening

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012, tcp

I've added an inbound connection rule for my windows 8 firewall on windows server 2012:

[image]

I've restarted the Windows Firewall.

When I check that port using this program, it says that it is not listening!

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How do I enable connections on TCP 42?**

Comment: Just because you add the rule doesn't mean it is listening...it just means the traffic is allowed.  If you do a `netstat -a -n` on the server does it show that it is actually running a service listening on port 42?  If so, what are the full details of the firewall inbound rule?

Comment: With netstat you can see the pid too, so in taskmgr you select to see the pid and you can see what is listening. If nothing then no app binded itselft to the port