# Enabling the Internet Connection on an EC2 Windows Server 2012 Machine

Tags: security, firewall, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I've disabled the firewall:

```
netsh firewall set opmode disable
```

I've made sure to accept all inbound and all outbound connections:

[image]

Is there anything that I should be installing or adding on to the server?

[image]

I am able to RDP into this computer without issue to the external IP address.

**How do I get a connection to the internet from this machine?**

---

There are actually two machines. Machine DC has no issues whatsoever with connecting to the internet, while machine Free1 cannot (although I can RDP into it).

The following are the settings for DC (the working machine):

[image]

While, these are the settings for the machine Free1, which does not have any internet connectivity (meaning that I cannot browse to any websites, or for example I am unable to run a Chrome install that requires an internet connection. How did I get the EXE onto the machine in the first place? I am able to copy and paste files from my local machine to these ec2 machines [regardless of whether they have internet connectivity]).

[image]

You are going to ask me how did I get the CHROME installation file on that machine? I can just copy and paste files from either virtual machine and my local physical machine to the virtual machines.

**How do I get internet connectivity for Free1?**

Also, a few more data points:

1. Both machines have been assigned the same security group.
2. Both machines are on the same subnet
3. Both machines have private and public IPs
4. I am able to RDP from my local physical machine into the ec2s.

Comment: What happens with: get-service -name "Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)" -computer

Comment: Um, have you actually tried connecting to the Internet?

Comment: @Fergus in response to your question http://screencast.com/t/HjgZ2xc0FJ

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I've tried with several browsers

Comment: What is your output from `ping google.com` and `ping 8.8.4.4`? If it's not the security group restricting outgoing, then something may be funky with your DNS settings.

Comment: @NathanC what is 8.8.4.4.?

Comment: @NathanC i am getting Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again   ---------- for both of those pings

Comment: @NathanC it looks like you're exactly right. i've changed DNS to point to the other machine and it started to work,. i need to figure out how to force the machine to get its DNS settings from amazon and not from the other machine

Comment: 8.8.4.4 is one of Google's DNS servers...just memorable enough to use for testing. :)

Comment: they must have paid a lot of money for it! i decided to try out azure and having weird issues with gateway: http://serverfault.com/questions/649746/user-account-not-listed-in-gateway-or-expecting-ip-address